#  how can I get string to be displayed if option is 'Single Option'

Tags: jquery, css

I cannot get this to work but if user selects "Single Choice", it should display the string "Single" and hide the textbox, else show textbox and hide the string "Single".

But it keeps displaying the textbox, no matter which option is chosen and I don't know why.

Jquery:

```
$('.numberAnswerTxt', context).each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $noofanswersText = '';

    if ($questionType == 'Single Option') {

        $noofanswersText = $("<span class='naRow string' style='display: inline-block;'>Single</span><input type='text' class='numberAnswerTxtRow answertxt' style='display: none;'>")
                               .attr('name', $this.attr('name'))
                               .attr('value', $this.val())

    } else {

        $noofanswersText = $("<span class='naRow string' style='display: none;'>Single</span><input type='text' class='numberAnswerTxtRow answertxt' style='display: inline-block;'>")
                               .attr('name', $this.attr('name'))
                               .attr('value', $this.val())

    }

    $noofanswers.append($noofanswersText);

});
```

Css:

```
.numberAnswerTxtRow{
    float:center;
    width:40px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:none;
}

.naRow{
    float:center;   
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to work : we can not apply `attr()` to some dynamically created element...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for

`alert( $this.val() )`

Comment: Yes that has worked for the alert. Now I have edit the question to solve the string and textbox display.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot decorate what is displayed by alert(), you cannot use css and the lookandfeel of the result of alert() depends on the browser you use.

I suggest using something like this [jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) that way you have control to what you want to display